# How to group pinned and running programs in the taskbar on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, pinning

I have started to use Windows 7. Programs can be "pinned" to the Taskbar. Internet Exporer was pinned there after installation, and when I start Internet Explorer no other icon is added to the Taskbar. I installed Google Chrome, it had the same behaviour on the Taskbar.

But now I have installed Eclipse and Spotify. I can pin them to the Taskbar, but when I click on them and start them the running program is shown as an additional icon. How can I make so they have the same behaviour as Internet Explorer and Google Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that problem with one or two bits of software.

I'm not sure of the cause, but there's a reasonably simple work-around that has been successful for me:

- **Close** and **unpin** the offending program.
- **Run** the program again.
- Right-click the icon for the running program on the taskbar and **pin** that.
  This element should now work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this work for Spotify, but not for Eclipse. I think it has to do with that Eclipse is a Java program that uses another program (.exe) to start it. At startup the "starter" program is closed and then only Eclipse is running.

Comment: @Jonas - well half way there at least. Check out this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314805) on the Eclipse website for your very problem, so it seems to be a known problem. Comments 29 and 35 may be useful, but otherwise there doesn't seem to be a "known to work" solution.

Comment: I have now installed *Eclipse Helios Service Release 1* and the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could check DMA's answer first... If that doesn't work:

You should run both programs in Windows Vista compatibility mode. The same thing happens with Windows Live Messenger.

Go to the program's root directory (e.g. `C:\Windows\Program Files\Spotify`), right click the program's main .exe file that is launched when clicking the shortcut. (Usually it's just the program's name like `spotify.exe`.) Click "Properties" in the context menu and go to the "Compatibility" tab. Then check the box "Run in compatibility mode:" Windows Vista.

Comment: DMA's answer worked only on Spotify, not on Eclipse. I tested your suggestion on Eclipse, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.